# UItableview scrolling problems under toolbar

Tags: uitableview, uitoolbar

I have a situation where I have a UItableview and a UIToolbar in my ViewController. The toolbar located at the bottom of the screen and the tableview takes up the whole screen. The problem is when I scroll down to the end of the table view and then release, it jumps back up to the top of the view instead of staying where I want to see. I know it has something to do with the position of the toolbar but I dont know how to solve it. Can anyone help me? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should help: `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)`. Replace '44'  with actual height of your toolbar. If it works then adjust in the same way `scrollIndicatorInsets` property.